# How can I initiate a list with a list element in julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to make a list of list in julia. It should be like this:

```
a = [1,"char", [1, 2, 3]]
a[3]
# ouput should be [1,2,3]
```

However, julia automatically does concatenation, so it ends up to be `[1, "char", 1, 2, 3]`

How can I do such things in julia without initiating the list with another value and then assigning a list to it like:

```
a = [1, "char", 3]
a[3] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
julia> a = Any[1,"char", [1, 2, 3]]
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
  "char"
  [1,2,3]
```

The style of array concatenation have been changes, now to concat arrays, the right syntax is: `a = [1;"char"; [1, 2, 3]]`, so `[1;"char"; [1, 2, 3]]==Any[1;"char"; [1, 2, 3]] # => true` but when Julia faces `[1,"char", [1, 2, 3]]` by default it tries to concat possible element types.

Comment: @Chong Wang you could also use `Vector[...]` and even `Vector{T}[...]` if your array of arrays is homogeneous, example: `Vector{Int}[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` will create a `2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}: [[1,2],[3,4]]`.